# How to Setting up single sign-on (SSO) between IBM WebSphere Portal and openam

Tags: single-sign-on, websphere-portal, openam

I want to configure IBM Websphere portal with openam...
I have done a bit of R&D but i can not come to any conclusion

how to achieve that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the WebSphere J2EE agent?

If this does not work you could write a custom TAI using OpenAM Java SDK ... that's what a J2EE agent is  ... a deployment container specific part and a servlet filter.